# Background Images CSS & Text

Tags: html, css, image

I want to update my site having text in the front and using background images in the back of my webpages (I want to do this for SEO optimization), what is the best html/css way to do this?

The current way I am doing this is not rendering correctly in IE8, but IS rendering properly in Firefox:

(Try this link in both IE8 and in Firefox)
https://drchrono.com/dental-practice-management-software/

Comment: Hell the page does not even completely show in Opera...

Comment: If you have only 1 background image (I couldn't see anything - IE6) then use background-image. You can google it for the syntax explanation.

Comment: Thanks for testing for me guys, I may just try one big image.

Comment: You really need to better explain what you're trying to do. Do you mean the images in the left column on that page? If so, you may as well remove the text from the images since you have the exact same headings on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently using a background on what seems to be actual content. My advice is - use backgrounds only for layouts, not for content.

Image tags score higher because of the "alt" tag and as a bonus people can find them with an image search.

Comment: not only that.. but name the files something meaningful to the image.   This also helps in google's image search.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any background images in your sample page. If you just want to add a background image to your body tag with css it could be as simple as

```
<style>
body {background-image:url('background.gif');}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you continue with the background issue I suggest you first try to get your site to validate. There are a few small issues that may be causing the page to not render properly in IE/Opera. Like the `<style>` within a `<td>`. Once the site validates it'll be much easier to do diagnostics, esp. with a problem like the one you're experiencing.

For a bonus you'll have improved SEO if your site validates. For an interesting read regarding validation & SEO: [SEO & Importance of Valid Source Code](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-importance-of-valid-source-code-w3c-validation/5166/)